# Wordpress: category title background image

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress template which has a module called new_boxs.
From the below code it displays itself on the page 6 times, 2 columns wide with three rows down like so:

```
foreach($data_cat as $cat){ ?>
    <div class="span6">
        <h2 class="ribbon ribbon-green">
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat ); ?>" ><?php echo get_cat_name( $cat ); ?></a>
        </h2>
.....
```

The h2 class 'ribbon' has the background image for the category heading and the heading link prints fine on top of it. (as per attached image)

What I need to do is have a different background for each of the 6 categories displayed on the front page.

Here is how I have it so far:

```
foreach($data_cat as $cat){ ?>
    <div class="span6">
        <?php if ( in_category( 'Science News' )) {
        echo '<h2 class="ribbon ribbon-green">'; 
        } elseif (in_category('Biological Sciences' )) {
        echo '<h2 class="ribbon2 ribbon-green">';
        }
        ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat ); ?>" ><?php echo get_cat_name( $cat ); ?></a>
    </h2>
....
```

The problem I'm having is that it does not grab the css background (no h2 or any class below it), it just shows the category link with no background.

[Link to image showing problem (before and after)](http://orbit.webuhostu.com/category_background.jpg)

Thanks guys,

Comment: What query are you doing to get $data_cat?

Comment: Yeah, after thinking about it, what I've written cannot identify which category it will be as it gets the specific category links later. So it would need a bit of rewriting, so I'm back to square one trying to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try:

```
foreach($data_cat as $cat){ ?>
    <div class="span6">
        <?php if (get_cat_name($cat) == 'Science News') {
        echo '<h2 class="ribbon ribbon-green">'; 
        } elseif (get_cat_name($cat) == 'Biological Sciences' ) {
        echo '<h2 class="ribbon2 ribbon-green">';
        }
        ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat ); ?>" ><?php echo get_cat_name( $cat ); ?></a>
    </h2>
```

Since you are printing the category name (in the link). Comparing that name to 'Science News' or 'Biological Sciences' should work.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I added a few more elseif{ for all the remainder of the cats and ended on an else{.
Perfect Thankyou.